# Regex To Match Code Comment

Tags: php, regex, netbeans

I have a bunch of files with comments on netbeans, I am using netbeans to replace strings that match a certain regex pattern, I'm lost on it. The comments have the following pattern below.

```
import static java.util.Arrays.*;
/* 178 */     int h = 8;
/* 179 */     int d = 8;
/* 180 */     int j = 8;
/* 181 */     int a = 6;
/*     */
```

I tried using `[\\\*\d+\*\/]` it removes the comments and the digits inside but it also removed the digit after the variable assignments, i.e it removed the `8` in `int h = 8;` and also removed the `*` in the import declaration.

Please help, tell me what I'm doing wrong, I just need to remove the comments with both the numbers and white-space in it. Thanks.

It uses the same regex pattern as PHP's `preg_replace();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take out the brackets. They create a character class, which means that any `*`, `/`, `\`, `+`, or digit is removed.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand. -_-

Comment: The brackets that are around your entire regular expression. They shouldn't be there. Look up in any regular expression guide ever what brackets do. Try this one: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression A "character class" - a list of characters inside square brackets - matches any one of the characters inside, in your case that's a `*`, `/`, `\`, `+`, or `\d`. Since all those characters match, they are all removed.

Comment: Aren't those the delimiters? I thought they are necessary? See http://codepad.org/6XWgE0LR

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use the following regex:

```
/\/\*\s*\d*\s*\*\//
```

(It's \d* and not \d+ only because I've noticed blank comments in your example)

Actually, if I were using preg_replace, then for higher readability I would've used the following:

```
$str = preg_replace('%/\*\s*\d*\s*\*/%U', '', $str);
```

Note that for preg_replace() I've added the U modifier, which turns off the "greediness". I'm not sure how to do this in Netbeans.